# is there any way to take an int turn it into a string and then into an int again

Tags: c#, int, tostring

i want to get the length of a number. i know i can do it with a while loop and dividing by 10 until the number reaches 0 but that takes around 10 line of code and i'm thinking it would be much quicker and much much more efficient to do it this way.

```cs
using System;

int[] array = new int[5]{1,12,123,1234,12345};
int[] length = new int[array.Length];
int i = 0;

while (i < 0)
{
    length[i] = int.Parse(((array[i]).ToString()).Length);
    i++;
}

i = 0;
while (i < array.Length)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", length);
    i++;
}
```

for some reason when i tell it to print the code length of each number instead of printing the length(1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5) in just prints system.int32[] 5 times

Comment: With `Console.Write("{0} ", length);` you're asking it to print the whole array, which is done on every iteration of the loop. You probably want: `Console.Write("{0} ", length[i]);` to print just the i'th element.

Comment: FYI the ToString() method is probably using same division method to convert number to string which you describe as inefficient.

Comment: @mightyWOZ Looking at the .NET Core source on GitHub shows that it is quite a bit more complicated than one could imagine https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/25520b174be2a8584e9d016a1eaa06b6120c8d6a/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Number.Formatting.cs#L688

Comment: @MindSwipe that was the point I was trying to make. OP was under the impression that code to extract digits from any number is ineffiecient compared to ToString.

Comment: @mightyWOZ My point is that complex != inefficient, sometimes complex is faster. While the ToString Method may be more complex than dividing by 10 over and over again, it is actually faster to do `ToString`, which shows that `ToString` does not use division by 10. [GitHub Gist I used to test](https://gist.github.com/MindSwipe/38411103f2aa72c272b7ea5c5ed90102), Dividing by 10 took roughly 5.1 ms and ToString and counting length took roughly 3.5 ms

Comment: @MindSwipe I agree with you that complex != inefficient. I merely stated that ToString probably uses same method to convert int to String, which is true. Please carefully read the definition of method UInt32ToDecStr in the source you linked.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to parse `.Length` since `Length` return `int`; your code amended:

```
  int[] array = new int[] {1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345};
  //TODO: you may want to put a better name here, say, digitCount
  // see comments below 
  int[] length = new int[array.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
    length[i] = array[i].ToString().Length;

  for (int i = 0; i < length.Length; ++i)
    Console.Write("{0} ", length[i]);
```

You can query `array` with a help of *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  int[] array = new int[] {1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345};

  int[] length = array
    .Select(item => item.ToString().Length)
    .ToArray();
```

And print `length` in one go with a help of `Join`:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(" ", length));
```

Comment: And this is a perfect example how naming can complicate things. Staying with the original code makes sense for the answer. But in real coding life it would make sense to change `int[] length` to something like `int[] digitCount`, which will make the code less confusing to read.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `length` is an array, and not the actual item (which I guess you want to print). The fix is easy, replace `Console.Write("{0} ", length);` with `Console.Write("{0} ", length[i]);`

Here a few tips for your code:

I see you are using `while` loops to iterate over something everywhere, so let me teach you a little about another type of loop, the `for` loop. The `for` is usually used to do something x amount of times and is constructed like so:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < length.Length; i++)
```

This might seem complicated but it's actually quite simple, let me explain. We can break down the `for` loop into 3 sections. The iterator declaration, the iterating condition, and the increment. `int i = 0` is the iterator declaration, here we declare and define a variable named `i` which is an `int` with the value `0`. In the next block (`i < length`) we declare the condition, when this condition is `true` we keep on going, when it is false we stop looping. And lastly is the increment or step (`i++`), this gets executed after every loop and increments the iterator (`i` in this case) by 1. Rewriting your code with `for` loops results in this:

```cs
int[] array = new int[] {1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345};
int[] length = new int[array.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    length[i] = int.Parse(((array[i]).ToString()).Length);
}

for (int i = 0; i < length.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ", length[i]);
}
```

This can still further be improved, for example, currently we are iterating twice over what is essentially the same data, which means we are wasting time. And also, since arrays are enumerable in C#, we can use a `foreach` loop. This is another type of loop which is almost the same as the `for` loop, but instead of doing something x amount of times we use to to something with every element of an enumerable. Using it we can do this:

```cs
int[] array = new int[] {1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345};

foreach (int element in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{element.ToString().Length} ");
}
```

I also used something called [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)(the `$` before the `"`)

Comment: For your string interpolation you switched the " and the }, and also forgot the space.

Comment: wow thank you so much for the tips its beyond anything i would have expected the only thing is that the fix didnt work now it just prints 0 5 times

Comment: nvm im stupid i forgot to change the i<0 to a i<array.length